# How to interact with Android ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I have created a ListView where I have to add different items. Now, when I click on a particular item it displays another window. On that window, I want to display the name of that item which I click on the ListView. 
My code:

```
private ListView contactList;
private String lv_arr[]={"Android","iPhone","BlackBerry","AndroidPeople"};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
{
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.contact_activity);
    contactList=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView01);    
    contactList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , lv_arr));
    contactList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
            /*Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), CallActivity.class);
                          startActivity(myIntent);*/
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to get the name of the item on itemclick event. pass it to the activity which will be called. in in the calling activity get the name of item and display

```
contactList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
             public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
String selecteditem = lv_arr[position]; 
                      Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), CallActivity.class);
                      intent.putExtra("item", selecteditem);
startActivity(myIntent);
                    }
                  });
```

### In CallActivity.java

write the following to get the selected item name

```
String selectedItem=getIntent().getStringExtra("item");
```

Comment: its running but nothing display in my on click of item it went to next activity but it doesnt display anythin..code i have written is String selectedItem=getIntent().getStringExtra("selecteditem");
         TextView textview = new TextView(this);
         textview.setText(selectedItem);
         setContentView(textview);

Comment: you should use String selectedItem=getIntent().getStringExtra("item");

Answer (score 0):

Instead of starting a new activity, use [AlertDialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html). You already have the position of the list item clicked. So displaying it on the dialog shouldn't be a problem if you follow the article linked.

EDIT : 
As per your requirement, you have to launch a new activity to display a string

In the sending list activity

```
intent.putExtra(String key, String value)
```

In receiving activity,

```
String value = getIntent().getStringExtra(key);
```

Comment: Actually i have to use new activity as per my assignment..can u please show me how that can be done but not in Alertdialog